# SQL error, Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure pro_update_last_read
(sensorID in sensor.sensor_id%type
, read_date in sensor.last_charged%type)
begin
    update sensor
    set last_charged = read_date 
    where sensor_id = sensorID;
end;
/
```

> Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

What is the problem with it?

Comment: What database is this?  Also, edit the question and use the code formatting option provided on the tool bar.

Comment: Entering `show errors` in the session would show you the details of what caused the error.

Comment: What tool are you using for your PL/SQL development? You should choose one that displays compilation errors, such as [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) (free from Oracle) or [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/bodyplsqldev.html) (licensed but worth it). We don't have Java developers saying "*My Java class says it has an error. What could it be?*" (Or do we?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS (or IS) is missing; apart from that, should be OK:

```
SQL> create table sensor
  2    (sensor_id number,
  3     read_date date,
  4     last_charged date);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure pro_update_last_read
  2  (sensorID in sensor.sensor_id%type
  3  , read_date in sensor.last_charged%type) as        --> here
  4  begin
  5      update sensor
  6      set last_charged = read_date
  7      where sensor_id = sensorID;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add keyword AS before begin and try again. If this doesnt help, please write your in parameters types here. And tag your database (rdbms) name.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the Word 'AS'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pro_update_last_read (
   sensorid    IN sensor.sensor_id%TYPE,
   read_date   IN sensor.last_charged%TYPE) 
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE sensor
      SET last_charged = read_date 
    WHERE sensor_id = sensorid;
END;
```